# Struts2 + jquery + session + jsp

Tags: jquery, hibernate, jsp, session, struts2

Hi I have a problem with session in struts2 and JSP. On the grid I display a list of all my DB. When inserting an element and refresh/reload the grid, there's no problem, but when I edit some element and refresh/reload, the grid brings me elements that are not referenced in my DB or not exist.

`DAO.java`:

```
public void actualizarGrupo(Long idGrupo, String nombreGrupo ){
    try {
        String queryString = "UPDATE dbo.TBL_SAG_GRUPO " +
                "SET NOMBRE_GRUPO='"+nombreGrupo+"' "+
                "WHERE ID_GRUPO="+idGrupo+"";
        System.out.println("Query que actualiza el grupo = " + queryString);
        SQLQuery queryObject = getSession().createSQLQuery(queryString);
        queryObject.executeUpdate();
    } catch (RuntimeException re)
    {

        throw re;
    }
}
```

Action.java

```
@Actions( { @Action(value = "/ajaxEnviarDatosGruposEdit", results = { @Result(name = "success", type = "json") }) })
public String modificarGrupo(){
    System.out.println(filtroIdGrupo+" "+filtroNombreGrupo);
    try {
        session.put(LISTA_GRUPOS,null);
        tblSagGrupoDAO= new TblSagGrupoDAO();
        tblSagGrupoDAO.actualizarGrupo(filtroIdGrupo, filtroNombreGrupoEdit);
        operResult =  "Grupo modificado satisfactoriamente";
        event="Modificar cuenta";
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    return SUCCESS;
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Actions( { @Action(value = "/ajaxBuscarGrupos", results = { @Result(name = "success", type = "json") }) })
public String buscarGrupos() {
    try {
        if (validarSesion()) {
            session.put(LISTA_GRUPOS, null);
            session.get(LISTA_GRUPOS);
            tblSagGrupoDAO= new TblSagGrupoDAO();
            System.out.println("--->Entro a buscar "+filtroNombreGrupo);
            List<TblSagGrupo> listaGrupoTemp = new ArrayList<TblSagGrupo>();

            if(filtroNombreGrupo.equals(null)||filtroNombreGrupo.isEmpty()) 
                listaGrupoTemp = (List<TblSagGrupo>) tblSagGrupoDAO.findAll();
            else
                listaGrupoTemp = (List<TblSagGrupo>) tblSagGrupoDAO.findByFilters(filtroNombreGrupo);// = (List<TblSagGrupo>) tblSagGruposDAO.findByFilters(filtroNombreGrupo);
            session.put(LISTA_GRUPOS, listaGrupoTemp);
        } else {
            redireccionarAlLogin("Modulo Contable");
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        return SUCCESS;

        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}
```

JSP

```
function enviarDatosEdit(){
            // Mostramos la imagen "Cargando"
            $("#imgCargando").show("highlight");
            // Cambiamos el puntero del mouse a "Cargando"
            $("body").css("cursor", "progress");


            var s = $("#gridListaGrupos").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');

            var idGrupo = $("#gridListaGrupos").jqGrid('getCell',s,'idGrupo');


            $.getJSON("ajaxEnviarDatosGruposEdit", {
                // Establecemos los parámetros
                filtroIdGrupo                   : idGrupo,
                //filtroNombreGrupo             : $("#filtroNombreGrupoAnterior").val(),
                filtroNombreGrupoEdit           : $("#filtroNombreGrupoEdit").val(),
                // Los siguientes parámetros deben ir por default (si no se ponen truena la búsqueda)                   
                sidx : "nombreGrupo", // campo por el cual se ordenará la lista
                sord : "asc" // orden de la lista
            },function(datos) // Función que se ejecuta cuando termina la petición ajax
              { 
                   /*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                   -- Marca del Cambio : WELL-JMQ-P-02-0271-13 Inicia la Modificacion   16/12/2013 -
                   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
                   // Volvemos a cargar el grid
                   $('#gridListaGrupos').trigger("reloadGrid", [{page:1}]);
                   jQuery("#gridListaGrupos").trigger("reloadGrid", [{page:1}]);
                    // Escondemos la imagen "Cargando"
                    $("#imgCargando").hide("highlight");
                    // Cambiamos el puntero del mouse a normal
                    $("body").css("cursor", "auto");
                    esconderFormEdit();
                }).error(function(){ 
                        window.location = 'login.jsp';
                    });
        }
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: sorry.. 
you'll agree with me, when you get the list of the database never have to change the value in the table, however, this changes when refreshing the table. that is the question, why the session is keeping values that no longer exist in the database?

Comment: Probably because you haven't updated values in the session.